# How to configure Atom linter-rubocop to run --rails flag always

Tags: ruby-on-rails, atom-editor, rubocop

I'm getting conflicting cops between my IDE and the console.  How do I have Atom's [linter-rubocop](https://atom.io/packages/linter-rubocop) to always run with the `--rails` flag?

#### Error in Atom:

[image]

#### Error in console:

[image]

This is my `config.cson`:

```
...

"linter-rubocop":
  command: "rubocop -R"
```

Answer (score 0):

The settings-page for `linter-rubocop` describes that the `command`-option should be provided with an absolute path. That is, the output of `which rubocop`. Then you can add the parameter.